# SQL many orders for some user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have asp.net website (Language :C#).
It's a store (User can order, Add to cart), every user have to sign in before doing that.
Example: user "X" logged in , and added a product ("Iphone 7") to his cart.
user "Y" logged in , and added the same prodcut (Iphone 7") to his cart.
how can I make a relationship in the SQL between the "Users" table and "Products" table that I can show in "My Cart" page the products that every user have added to his cart ?

Comment: you need a link table that has 2 columns, UserID and ProductID This way you create a many to many relationship. A user can have more than one product and a product can be for mare than one user

Comment: You can also have an extra field within a product table item which stores the unique identifiers (id/uid) as am array so all the users can be fetched for that product using the keys

Comment: What I mean is how to let the website know for each user what is his orders that he picked up ( getting them from sql-server table) , (I need an idea about how doing it and how to do it )

Comment: we need an idea of what exactly you are asking. Can you edit your question and elaborate please

Comment: I have edited my question , I hope that I explained it well this time :D

Comment: @GuidoG I have edited it, check it please :)

Comment: Yamen, look at Gordon's answer I think it covers exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would have two tables called `Carts` and `CartItems`, something like this:

```
create table Carts (
    CartId int identity primary key,
    BuyerId int references Users(UserId),
    CartDate datetime,
);

create table CartItems (
    CartItemId int identity primary key,
    CartId int references Carts(CartId),
    ProductId int references Products(ProductId),
    int quantity,
    price money
);
```

In other words, you want *two* tables, not a separate table for each user.  The information just goes in as separate rows in these tables.

This ensures:

- A user can have multiple carts, even on the same day.
- Carts can have multiple items.
- All items in a Cart are identified with that cart.

Comment: I think that you understood me, but still I didnt understood exactly what I have to do , how can I contact you ?

Comment: after doing that , how can I add a product to the user cart  , and how can I get it in "My Cart" page to show it for him ?